# Coordinate Id of same card that is read by two different card readers

Tags: c#, smartcard, mifare, cardreader

In a part of a software, card is read by a card reader and is allocated to an user. And in other part of this software, in a terminal by same card reader, the user card is read and fetch data from database by card serial number and etc.

In a new part of this software, there are a new terminal with a new card reader. card is read from this card reader and fetch data from database and etc.

So, now the problem is that a same card that is read by this two card readers are different in type. The first device return card id as a hexadecimal string, like this:

```
2E 6F 27 3F
```

This hexadecimal string is converted to decimal and is stored in the database. For example, the above hexadecimal string is converted to this integer:

```
779036479
```

Now, when second card reader read this same card, the card id is an array of bytes, like this for that card:

```
byte0: 49
byte1: 48
byte2: 53
byte3: 57
byte4: 53
byte5: 52
byte6: 56
byte7: 57
byte8: 55
byte9: 52
```

How can I coordinate this two serial number of same card with each other? In other words, I want to convert this array of bytes to corresponding hex code, so that this hex code is the serial number of that card that first device is return?

The card is Mifare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that the second reader is returning ASCII encoded decimals. Your number is `1059548974`. This number, encoded into hexadecimals is `3F276F2E` if you use Big Endian encoding. If you use Little Endian encoding then you will get `2E6F273F` which should be familiar to you.

So:

1. decode the returned byte array to ASCII, retrieving the string `"1059548974"`
2. convert that string to an integer using `Convert.ToUInt32(str);`
3. reverse the bytes in the integer

Probably the best way to reverse the bytes is this piece of code:

```
public static UInt32 ReverseBytes(UInt32 value)
{
  return (value & 0x000000FFU) << 24 | (value & 0x0000FF00U) << 8 |
         (value & 0x00FF0000U) >> 8 | (value & 0xFF000000U) >> 24;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its rather hard to understand just exactly what your wanting, but in the bottom you state: 'in other words, i want to convert this array of bytes to corresponding hex code'.

You can perform that operation like so:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
  foreach (byte b in ba)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Just pass in your Byte array and the result will be your hex conversion in string format.

Edit: This will probably yield the same results, but try this:

```
byte[ ] bytes = {0,   1,   2,   4,   8,  16,  32,  64, 128, 255 }
Console.WriteLine( BitConverter.ToString( bytes ) );
```

Comment: thank you, your code is returned this string: **3b303539353438393734**, but this is not equal to **2E 6F 27 3F**. the value **3b303539353438393734** is hexadecimal of a card id that is gained by your code. that card is read from _second_ device, while the value **2E 6F 27 3F** is a hexadecimal of card id that is read from _first_ device. this two value must be equal for synchronization purposes between two different card reader

Comment: Then your Byte Array is not equal to the Hex value.

Comment: See, one card is read by two different card readers. but the Id of this card that is gained by this card readers is different. i want to gain one Id for same card by this card readers.

Comment: thank you, this is true that your code is converted byte array to hexadecimal, but the hexadecimal result must be equal to hexadecimal result of card id for first card reader

Comment: Then there must be something that is different. Probably the way software 2 gets the hex. I would suggest doing some reverse engineering at this point and see how the software gets the hex. Its probably salting.